# How to fix the possible memory leak issue in Openlayers 2.13.1 version?

Tags: openlayers-2, performance, chrome

Recently we have upgraded the Openlayers from version 2.12 to 2.13.1. However the performance of the new version is not that promising, infact it has degraded exponentially. I have a draggable model window and once the base map has been loaded if I do the drag and drop operation over the top of the map window, the user experience is not so smooth as for 2.12 version. After some memory leak detection approach [three snapshot technique](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wUVmf78gG-ra5aOxvTfYdiLkdGaR9OhXRnOlIcEmu2s/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.g1d65bdf6_0_0), I found that there is some memory leakage issue in ***OpenLayers.Control.Navigation.OpenLayers.Class.initialize***. 
Is there any tuning need to be performed while upgrading to the new OL?
Did someone face the similar performance issue as well?
Thanks for your answers.